# PHP5-FPM is shutting down

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

My **php5-fpm** is shutting down without any trace in php5-fpm.log .

here is my php5-fpm.log

```
[03-Apr-2014 11:02:44] NOTICE: Finishing ...  
[03-Apr-2014 11:02:44] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!  
[03-Apr-2014 11:02:44] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 26184  
[03-Apr-2014 11:02:44] NOTICE: ready to handle connections  
[03-Apr-2014 11:02:57] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[11-Apr-2014 04:39:38] NOTICE: Finishing ...  
[11-Apr-2014 04:39:38] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!  
[11-Apr-2014 04:39:38] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 11145  
[11-Apr-2014 04:39:38] NOTICE: ready to handle connections  
[11-Apr-2014 04:41:42] NOTICE: Finishing ...  
[11-Apr-2014 04:41:42] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!  
[11-Apr-2014 04:41:42] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 12065  
[11-Apr-2014 04:41:43] NOTICE: ready to handle connections  
[11-Apr-2014 06:30:15] NOTICE: Finishing ...  
[11-Apr-2014 06:30:15] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!  
[11-Apr-2014 06:30:15] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 13070  
[11-Apr-2014 06:30:15] NOTICE: ready to handle connections  
[11-Apr-2014 10:35:34] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[11-Apr-2014 10:38:49] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[16-Apr-2014 07:34:49] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[28-Apr-2014 04:28:47] NOTICE: Finishing ...  
[28-Apr-2014 04:28:47] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!  
[28-Apr-2014 04:28:48] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 23381  
[28-Apr-2014 04:28:48] NOTICE: ready to handle connections  
[04-May-2014 22:29:33] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[05-May-2014 08:11:00] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[06-May-2014 00:49:42] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[06-May-2014 06:43:01] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[06-May-2014 09:15:26] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[07-May-2014 11:00:31] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (10), consider raising it  
[20-May-2014 03:00:34] NOTICE: Finishing ...  
[20-May-2014 03:00:34] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!  
[20-May-2014 03:00:34] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 13222  
[20-May-2014 03:00:35] NOTICE: ready to handle connections  
[22-May-2014 10:36:09] NOTICE: Finishing ...  
[22-May-2014 10:36:09] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!  
[22-May-2014 10:36:09] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 18402  
[22-May-2014 10:36:09] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Should i raise the **pm.max_children** , my configuration is:
CPU: 2.6 Mhz
RAM: 16 Gb

Also is there any chance that some other process is killing php5-fpm ?

Comment: Check also the *nginx* logs (`/var/log/nginx/...`). Also some of your *exits* have very "on the clock" time, don't you have some crontabs that could end the process(es)?

Comment: yes i noticed that let me get my nginx log.

Comment: Hi ,@ring0 my nginx/error.log file is empty , there is some content in
error.log.1 but it is irrelevant

Comment: Please post your PHP conf.